# If Application_end is called during recycle, how can I fire again Application_Start?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5

I have the need to implement a very light task scheduler, and I am a newbie ASP.NET Guy (I have a strong Java knowledge anyway). I have seen this idea

http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/Scheduled-Tasks.aspx

which is based on a cache expiration trigger, which is better then a wild thread in my huble opinion :)

Now the problem: my IIS server has a very tight idle timeout (20minutes) so my Application_End is called often.

(See [When exactly does Application_End get called and how can I manually cause this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/955594/when-exactly-does-application-end-get-called-and-how-can-i-manually-cause-this/955776#955776) )

There is a fair way to force at least a call to my application_start again, to keep the scheduler running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/ASPNETService.aspx) article by Omar. Here he discusses how to take care of recycle app pool.
Basic you need to either

- Hit the app url using automation.
- Or register with some third party
  services that are type of ping
  services which can ping your site on
  predefined time interval.
- Or register with search engines which cause link\page crawls.